# ASP web application issues with jquery datetime picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4

I am attempting to place the bootstrap-datetimepicker by eonasdan in a C# gridview cell. I am facing issues with the elements not appearing correctly. Only the time is showing up and not the calendar. There are places for direction arrows on the element but they are not showing up either which makes me think it is a css issue and not a jquery or html issues. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I have tried rearranging and trying different .js and .min.js references. I have tried several of the different html layouts as provided on the documentation.

```html
<script src=".../jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src=".../moment.js"></script>
<script src=".../bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src=".../bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".../bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".../bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
…
<div class="containter">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dt1" />
      </div>
      <script>
        $(function () {
          $('#dt1').datetimepicker();
        });
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There popup does work and it shows the time element, but the arrows to make the time go up and down are not appearing and the actual calendar itself is not showing up.

EDIT: I am now able to use the plugin with all of the textboxes but things are still not appearing as they should be. Here is the updated code. The datetime picker is still not appearing completely though.

```html
<script src=".../jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src=".../moment.js"></script>
<script src=".../bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src=".../bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".../bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href=".../bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" />
…
<div class="containter">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="dt1" cssclass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
      </div>
      <script>
        $(function () {
          $('.form-control').datetimepicker();
        });
      </script>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you get console errors? If not i think you are correct about css

Comment: No console errors.

Comment: I wonder if the version of jquery is affecting it?

Comment: "a C# gridview cell" - i see ids here. is this by chance in a grid row that repeats, which would result in multiple elements with the same id?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I can get  the pop up to function in the first row, but even then not all of the elements of it are displaying.

Comment: IDs must be unique for the page. That's just the html rules and jquery needs it to obey that. Use a class or other selector, like data-id, instead. Use something that is unique for that cell though or your selector will cause multiple matches and headaches. A row + column id, whatever.

Comment: You mean like assign the script to target $('.form-control').datetimepicker(); since it only appears in that specific cell? This way all of them should be targeted.

Comment: So I did that and now it works for all of them. I was also able to use asp:TextBox so I'll be able to grab the data however the entire pop up is still not appearing.

Comment: No, it needs a single target to open, not all of them. Generate a unique id however you like and use that. Don't group them for this. You can group them by class for saving/submitting if you need to, but the date picker div needs one element. You may still have to mess with positioning if it gets cut off.

Comment: But I can make it work in all of the cell. I tried on a separate element outside of the gridview to see if I could make it perform like it should but it is still the same problem. I am using all up to date .js and .css files but the calendar is not appearing. It should look like the examples at http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/